# UIPageViewController with transition style Scroll autoplay wrong video

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift2, xcode7, uipageviewcontroller

I have a 2 dimensional UIPageViewController (Two PageViewController, one horizontal, and one vertical).
On the first level (X = 0), I display full screen videos with autoplay. When i'm using transition style Page Curl, i have no problems, but with transition style Scroll, the fact that the "after view controller" is preloaded, it will execute the code and autoplay the video (hosted on youtube) before, therefore, it will stop the video which on the view controller i'm actually seeing, and also, i will hear that video in the background.

I can't figure how to make sure that the video that is playing is one i'm really looking at.

this is how I set my view:

import UIKit

class YViewController: UIViewController {

```
var yPageIndex: Int!
var xPageIndex: Int!
var yLabelText: String!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if (xPageIndex == 0) {      // if xPageIndex == 0 then you are on the tag page. Else, you are browsing

        // HOME SCREEN
        let homeLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height))

       //  homeLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        // homeLabel.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2, self.view.frame.size.height / 2)
        // homeLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        homeLabel.numberOfLines = 0

        let htmlString = "<center><h1>Welcome John Smith</h1> <h2> Your Tags: </h2> <i> #unity #iOS #php #XCODE</i><br><br><br><br><br><br> <i>Swipe left to start browsing job offers</i></center>"

        let encodedData = htmlString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        let attributedOptions = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType]
        do {
            let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
            homeLabel.attributedText = attributedString

        } catch _ {
            print("Cannot create attributed String")
        }

               self.view.addSubview(homeLabel)

    } else {


        if yPageIndex == 0 {    // if yPageIndex == 0 then you are on video page. Else, you are on the job description page

            var webView = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame)

            view.addSubview(webView)
            view.bringSubviewToFront(webView)


            webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
            webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false
            webView.scrollView.bounces = false

            let videoID =  mainInstance.jobInfoArray[xPageIndex].videoId

            let embededHTML = "<html><body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'><script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script><script type='text/javascript'>function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){ytplayer=new YT.Player('playerId',{events:{onReady:onPlayerReady}})}function onPlayerReady(a){a.target.playVideo();}</script><iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='\(self.view.frame.size.width)' height='\(self.view.frame.size.height)' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/\(videoID)?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=1&autoplay=0&controls=0' frameborder='0'></body></html>"
            webView.loadHTMLString(embededHTML, baseURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().resourceURL)
            print("width='\(self.view.frame.size.width)' height='\(self.view.frame.size.height)'")

        } else {

            print("Job " + mainInstance.jobInfoArray[xPageIndex].jobTitle)


            print("width='\(self.view.frame.size.width)' height='\(self.view.frame.size.height)'")
            var homeLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 30, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height))


            homeLabel.numberOfLines = 0

            let htmlString = "<h1>\(mainInstance.jobInfoArray[xPageIndex].jobTitle)</h1> <h2>Company: \(mainInstance.jobInfoArray[xPageIndex].jobCompany) </h2> <i> tags: \(mainInstance.jobInfoArray[xPageIndex].jobKeyWords)</i><br>Salary: \(mainInstance.jobInfoArray[xPageIndex].jobSalary)<br> <br> \(mainInstance.jobInfoArray[xPageIndex].jobDescription)"

            let encodedData = htmlString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            let attributedOptions = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType]
            do {
                let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
                homeLabel.attributedText = attributedString

            } catch _ {
                print("Cannot create attributed String")
            }
            homeLabel.sizeToFit()
            self.view.addSubview(homeLabel)





            }
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

and this how I configured my UIPageView

class XViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

```
// to init y display

var yPageViewController: UIPageViewController!
var yLabel: NSArray!



// To remove ?
var xPageIndex: Int!
var videoTitleText: String!




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // self.videoLabel.text = self.videoTitleText

    self.yLabel = NSArray(objects: "Video", "Job Description")

    self.yPageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("yPageViewController") as! UIPageViewController

    self.yPageViewController.dataSource = self

    let startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0) as YViewController
    let viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC)

    self.yPageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as! [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    self.yPageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width , self.view.frame.size.height)

    self.addChildViewController(self.yPageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(self.yPageViewController.view)
    self.yPageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



func viewControllerAtIndex(yIndex: Int) -> YViewController
{

    if ( (self.yLabel.count == 0) || (yIndex >= self.yLabel.count) ) {

        return YViewController()
    }

    let vc: YViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("yContentViewController") as! YViewController

    vc.yPageIndex = yIndex
    vc.xPageIndex = xPageIndex
    vc.yLabelText = self.yLabel[yIndex] as! String





    return vc

}


// MARK: Page View Controller Data Source



func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let vc = viewController as! YViewController
    var yIndex = vc.yPageIndex as Int

    if ( (yIndex == 0)  || (yIndex == NSNotFound) ) {
        return nil
    }

    yIndex--
    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(yIndex)

}



func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let vc = viewController as! YViewController
    var yIndex = vc.yPageIndex as Int

    if (yIndex == NSNotFound || xPageIndex == 0)  {
        return nil
    }

    yIndex++

    if (yIndex == self.yLabel.count)
    {
        return nil
    }

    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(yIndex)

}

func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return 0
}
```

}

and just in case, here the ViewConytoller (the fact that it goes horizontal and vertical might makes it a bit hard to figure out.

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

```
var xPageViewController: UIPageViewController!
var videoId: NSArray!
```

//    var yPageViewController: UIPageViewController!
//    var jobId: NSArray!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.videoId = NSArray(objects: "Video #1", "Video #2", "Video #3", "Video #4", "Video #5")

    self.xPageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("xPageViewController") as! UIPageViewController

    self.xPageViewController.dataSource = self

    let startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0) as XViewController
    let viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC)

    self.xPageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as! [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    self.xPageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width , self.view.frame.size.height)

    self.addChildViewController(self.xPageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(self.xPageViewController.view)
    self.xPageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

}





override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func viewControllerAtIndex(xIndex: Int) -> XViewController
{

    if ( (self.videoId.count == 0) || (xIndex >= self.videoId.count) ) {

        return XViewController()
    }

    let vc: XViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("xContentViewController") as! XViewController

    vc.xPageIndex = xIndex
    vc.videoTitleText = self.videoId[xIndex] as! String



    return vc

}





// MARK: Page View Controller Data Source

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let vc = viewController as! XViewController
    var xIndex = vc.xPageIndex as Int

    if ( (xIndex == 0)  || (xIndex == NSNotFound) ) {
        return nil
    }

    xIndex--
    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(xIndex)

}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let vc = viewController as! XViewController
    var xIndex = vc.xPageIndex as Int

    if (xIndex == NSNotFound)  {
        return nil
    }

    xIndex++

    if (xIndex == self.videoId.count)
    {
        return nil
    }

    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(xIndex)

}

func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return 0
}
```

}

I'm new to this, so i'm sorry if i'm not clear or if I'm not following the "posting rules" for this site.
If anyone as any ideas on how i could achieve that, that would be brilliant.

Thanks a lot,

Julien

Comment: I would recommend posting a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem, rather than your code verbatim.

Comment: thanks, i just did, and i made a new post to make it easier to understand. hope this is ok. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313400/uipageviewcontroller-with-transition-style-scroll-issue